# usercontrol datacontext different usings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, datacontext

when i write :

```
    <UserControl>
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <loca:DataBindingDemo></loca:DataBindingDemo>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTime}" Height="30" Background="Aqua" Margin="133,141,169,140"></TextBox>

    </UserControl>
```

with xmlns:loca="clr-namespace:MyClock"

it is currect and there is no problem,but when i write:

```
 <UserControl  DataContext="{Binding Source=clr-namespace:MyClock.DataBindingDemo}">
        <!--
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <loca:DataBindingDemo></loca:DataBindingDemo>
        </UserControl.DataContext>
        -->

        <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTime}" Height="30" Background="Aqua" Margin="133,141,169,140"></TextBox>

    </UserControl>
```

or

```
    <UserControl  DataContext="{Binding  Source=StaticResource, Path=clr-namespace:MyClock.DataBindingDemo}">
        <!--
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <loca:DataBindingDemo></loca:DataBindingDemo>
        </UserControl.DataContext>
        -->

        <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTime}" Height="30" Background="Aqua" Margin="133,141,169,140"></TextBox>

    </UserControl>
```

it does not work! why?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it does not work! why?

`clr-namespace:` is used to create a namespace mapping to custom classes and assemblies and can't be used directly like that in markup extension, it is **not** a namespace prefix.

**Edit:** You can't use local types in your assembly directly in your markup extension like that.

First you will have to create a namespace mapping like you have done in your question like this: `xmlns:local="clr-namepsace:YOUR_ASSEMBLY_NAME.NAMESPACE_CONTAINING_TYPE_YOU_WANT"`.

Then you can use them in markup extensions like this:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source=local:MyClock.DataBindingDemo}">
//                                          ^
//                                          |
//                                   Notice namespace using here
```

Comment: Iused these two , but the same result:

<UserControl  DataContext="{Binding  Source=StaticResource, Path=MyClock.DataBindingDemo}">
<UserControl  DataContext="{Binding  Source=MyClock.DataBindingDemo}">

Comment: @abdolah I have edited the answer to cover your comment, please check edit.

Comment: ok thanks.(for every things there is Zakat and Zakat of science is publishing it .shia Emam Ali )